# MongoDB Replica Sets - Who tells secondary servers about oplog updates?

Tags: mongodb

So i've been studying MongoDB for some time now and i am starting to learn not only how to do things, but how these things are actually done.

According to the  [Official Documentation on data Replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/)  all changes to the Primary node are written on the Operation log, ie oplog, and the secondary servers copy those changes. What i could not find in the official documentation, or any other source for that matter, who is responsible for communicating when the Primary oplog is changed.

Does the Primary Server let Secondary Servers know that there were new operations on the Oplog and they go fetch it, or the Secondary Servers check the oplog from time to time? Or is that a configuration when creating a replica set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Secondary members replicate data continuously after the initial sync
>   and copy the oplog from their `sync from source` and apply these
>   operations in an asynchronous process.

In most cases, secondaries sync from the primary.

> Secondaries may automatically change their `sync from source` if needed
>   based on changes in the ping time and state of other members’
>   replication.
>
> Secondries avoid synching from the delayed members or hidden memebers.

**Secondry keeps on pinging the primary server for the oplog file, and if it is not available for more than 10sec, then It calls for an election.**

Took this from the official document only at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-sync/

Comment: I see that most of things are indeed in the link, but i could not find where it says that the secondary keeps pinging. But it's on your answer, so Thanks a lot! Really cleared things out and helped to better understand when elections are made.

Comment: Caio :- I am writing a blog on mongo elections, will share the link once it is done. Mean while you can go through this blog of my to learn mongo tunning, for future performance issues. http://nkgupta1989.github.io/Mongo-Performance-Tunning/